# MySQL INSERT ... SET ... ON DUPLICATE KEY failing... puzzled

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, syntax-error

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this query:

```
INSERT `user` 
SET 
    `password` = SHA1('abc'), 
    `username` = 'admin'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPADTE `password` = SHA1('abc')
```

It results in (MySQL 5.6.11):

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'UPADTE `password` = SHA1('abc')' at line 5

Yet I can't figure out what's wrong with my syntax. From the MySQL manual:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

check the spelling of you UPDATE in your sql statement. It should be UPDATE not UPADTE.